# Unable To Install PyAudio On A Mac Even With HomeBrew Installed

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

I am on a macOS system and I am not able to install PyAudio On a Mac even with using the portaudio and homebrew technique . What should I do ? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

PyAudio is a python package, so you need to install it with pip. Try running `pip install pyaudio` or `pip3 install pyaudio` depending on which version of python you are using.

Comment: I already tried this but it is still not working . Thanks For At Least Answering though (:

Comment: @ProgrammingWithNaman did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: No Not Yet . I need to submit my project in 5 days so please help as. this is necessary for the project .